# Kibana skipping Plugins

Tags: kibana

I have shield installed as a plugin, in `/installedPlugins/shield` in Kibana.
when I start kibana, there is warning log message says: `Skipping non-plugin directory at /path/installedPlugins/shield`
Why is it skipping it?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have installed the wrong shield meant for elasticsearch (.zip). You need to install shield for kibana (tar.gz). http://download.elastic.co/kibana/shield/shield-2.4.0.tar.gz

Remove the plugin and reinstall the kibana shield plugin. Restart kibana and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is skipping it, because Shield is not a valid Kibana plugin.

There's an open issue about this (https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/6148) which has yet to be fixed, but it is only labelled P3 (priority 3 => "nice-to-have bug fix")

Comment: thank you. But do you know which version of shield is a valid plugin?

Comment: How did you install Shield? Here is the procedure: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/kibana.html

Comment: Yup followed those directions

Comment: Note that it's not an error, simply a warning because the Shield plugin is not a valid Kibana plugin even though it is installed as such. Does your Kibana/Shield setup work?

Comment: It works with elasticsearch. Tested it. But after starting Kibana, there is log in screen, like the screenshot in that tutorial. Using Kibana 4.3, shield 2.3

Comment: That log is just a warning you can disregard.

Comment: I also dont get the log-in screen, like where it ask you to log in? After starting Kibana with shield